# Every 3 div wrapped in a div

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I output data using ACF Pro. I need no more than 3 elements of div with class "block" to be displayed in div with class "in".

Just started working with advanced custom fields in wordpress and PHP is very bad, but I'm learning). I apologize for my poor English.

Here's my loop:

```
<div class="in">
    <?php if( have_rows('fourth-section_tariffs') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('fourth-section_tariffs') ): the_row(); 
        $tariffs_number = get_sub_field('fourth-section_tariffs_number');
        $tariffs_title = get_sub_field('fourth-section_tariffs_title');
        $tariffs_cost = get_sub_field('fourth-section_tariffs_cost');
        $tariffs_sale_text = get_sub_field('fourth-section_tariffs_sale_text');
    ?>
    <div class="block">
        <p class="title"><?php echo $tariffs_number; ?></p>
        <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'fourth-section_tariffs_sale' ) == 1 ) { ?>
            <span class="sale"><?php echo $tariffs_sale_text; ?></span>
            <?php
                } else {
            } ?>
            <h3><?php echo $tariffs_title; ?></h3>
            <div class="price"><?php echo $tariffs_cost; ?></div>
            <ul>
                <?php if( have_rows('fourth-section_tariffs_marked') ): ?>
                <?php while( have_rows('fourth-section_tariffs_marked') ): the_row(); 
                    $tariffs_marked_text = get_sub_field('fourth-section_tariffs_marked_text');
                ?>
                <li><?php echo $tariffs_marked_text; ?></li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>     
            </ul>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?> 
</div>
```

The output is so:

```
<div class="in">
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

And need to so:

```
<div class="in">
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="in">
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening and closing the div with "in" class out of the while and it cause your output with a div in beginning and the close in end.

To solve that, you need to pass the div creation for inside while loop and create a counter to check if the counter module 3 (counter%3) is 0. Always with that occur, the div will print in the start (and will close the before div). Here the code:

```
<?php if( have_rows('fourth-section_tariffs') ): ?>
    <?php 
    $loop_counter = 0;
    while( have_rows('fourth-section_tariffs') ): the_row(); 

        if($loop_counter%3 == 0){
            //if not is the first interaction we will first close the last openned that for open another after
            if($loop_counter > 0){
                ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <div class="in">
            <?php
        }

        $tariffs_number = get_sub_field('fourth-section_tariffs_number');
        $tariffs_title = get_sub_field('fourth-section_tariffs_title');
        $tariffs_cost = get_sub_field('fourth-section_tariffs_cost');
        $tariffs_sale_text = get_sub_field('fourth-section_tariffs_sale_text');

    ?>
    <div class="block">
        <p class="title"><?php echo $tariffs_number; ?></p>
        <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'fourth-section_tariffs_sale' ) == 1 ) { ?>
            <span class="sale"><?php echo $tariffs_sale_text; ?></span>
            <?php
                } else {
            } ?>
            <h3><?php echo $tariffs_title; ?></h3>
            <div class="price"><?php echo $tariffs_cost; ?></div>
            <ul>
                <?php if( have_rows('fourth-section_tariffs_marked') ): ?>
                <?php while( have_rows('fourth-section_tariffs_marked') ): the_row(); 
                    $tariffs_marked_text = get_sub_field('fourth-section_tariffs_marked_text');
                ?>
                <li><?php echo $tariffs_marked_text; ?></li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>     
            </ul>
    </div>
    <?php 
        $loop_counter++;
    endwhile;
    //close the last div
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I had tested and worked like a charm for me. I have created a sandbox without your functions for test proposes to: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5dbdd02d887bf47eddcd208f41bb189c0e9fed97

Comment: Thank you! It works and it's a great experience for me!